# Module not found - NexrJs

Tags: css, next.js, frontend

I have just started learning NextJs, one of the problems i am facing is that whenever I create a page that is the child of App

App

- About

  - page.js
  - loading.js
- Dashboard

  - page.js
  - loading.js

My structure is something like this. Now if i ever delete the loading.js for any one of the pages (about / dashboard) my application breaks. It shows me the error "Module not found" '/home/icecube/Desktop/nextjs_tut/src/app/about/error.jsx'

Initially when loading.js was not present the application was working fine but if i created it while following a tutorial and now i want to delete it, the application seems to break. This issue also seems to extend when i create a "page.module.css" file for a particular folder (let's say about) now in the page.js (of about) when i import it as
import styles from "./page.module.css" and apply the className as {styles.container}. then also similar message is received.

Edit :I am able to resolve this when i delete the cache folder in .next (not apt solution i believe)

What is happening and how to resolve this ?

Comment: Please share your code for the app component. We do not know what your routing looks like or which component calls which one or what any of these components does

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and debugging steps.

Comment: @AniketPandey i just created a new project, added a folder in app directory and under that i created 2 files (page.js and loading.js) Everything was working fine. Now I deleted the loading.js file -> reproducing the error. Next does not requires routing manually we can do it by the files (page, loading, error etc) and folder structure.
My thought process ->  is it being cached by next and hence the error -> removed the whole cache folder (including fall back T_T) in .next -> error gone for now. it just seems like a bad solution as i don't understand the workings clearly

Comment: @AniketPandey all my components are empty function with just their name as return value in a div

{import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
 <div>App</div>
  )
}

export default App}


same for all the files.